# How do I search nested json query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, json, nested

I am using MySQL 5.7+ with the native `JSON` data type.

Sample data:

```
set @jsn_string='{\"body\": {\"items\": \"[{\\\"count\\\":530,\\\"id\\\":5},{\\\"count\\\":1,\\\"id\\\":519},{\\\"count\\\":209,\\\"id\\\":522},{\\\"count\\\":0,\\\"id\\\":3004}] \"}}';
```

Questions: the correct answer is 530

The following query has the position of the data

```
select json_extract(@jsn_string,'$.body.items[0].id[0]');
```

but the result is : `null`

Answer (score 1):

we can use `json_unquote` to remove those double quotes in `items[0]`

```
set @jsn_string='{\"body\": {\"items\": \"[{\\\"count\\\":530,\\\"id\\\":5},{\\\"count\\\":1,\\\"id\\\":519},{\\\"count\\\":209,\\\"id\\\":522},{\\\"count\\\":0,\\\"id\\\":3004}] \"}}';


select json_extract(json_unquote(json_unquote(json_extract(@jsn_string, '$.body.items[0]')))
    ,'$[0].count');
```

see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=hCPJDw6E0z)

Comment: that's my point, my json is invalid
it works well using with replace~!

Comment: another question~! how can i extracted iterated key,values ?

id[0], count[0]
id[1], count[1]
~~~~~~~~~~
id[n], count[n]

Comment: @Aiden, this should be in separate question, if there were 5 people who answered this question, they will be all invalid.

Comment: @metal this ismy new question. please help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58932899/how-do-i-search-iterated-loop-json-data-in-mysql

Comment: @Aiden, sorry, but i'm not sure if you are accepting answers or at least vote for the efforts done.

Answer (score 0):

As per your sample JSON, id is not an array. So `id[0]` wont work As I understand from your question, you want to retrieve 530. For this you can use the following.

```
select json_extract(@jsn_string,'$.body.items[0].count');
```

Please let me know if I understood it incorrectly.

Edit - 1:
I think your json is invalid. Array should not be wrapped in braces. Try this

```
@jsn_string='{\"body\": {\"items\": [{\\\"count\\\":530,\\\"id\\\":5},{\\\"count\\\":1,\\\"id\\\":519},{\\\"count\\\":209,\\\"id\\\":522},{\\\"count\\\":0,\\\"id\\\":3004}]}}';
```

Comment: result is null , 
no way to retrieve 530 ?