# how do i search iterated loop json data in mysql?

Tags: mysql, json, loops

I am using MySQL 5.7+ with the native JSON data type.

Sample data:

```
set @jsn_string='{\"body\": {\"items\": \"[{\\"count\\":530,\\"id\\":5},{\\"count\\":1,\\"id\\":519},{\\"count\\":209,\\"id\\":522},{\\"count\\":0,\\"id\\":3004}]\"}}';
```

Questions:

i want to retrieve iterated key, value.

The following result has the position of the data

```
select json_extract(replace(replace(replace(trim(@jsn_string), '\"[', '['), ']\"', ']'), '\\"', '\"'),'$.body.items[0].id') as id,
json_extract(replace(replace(replace(trim(@jsn_string), '\"[', '['), ']\"', ']'), '\\"', '\"'),'$.body.items[0].count') as count;
```

result is 
id    count
5      530

but i want all of array, such as below

`id[0] count[0],
id[1] count[1],
id[n] count[n]`

Comment: ideally upgrade to MySQL 8 where you have JSON_TABLE().. Otherwise look into a [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55359984/2548147) which i posted before to simulate JSON_TABLE() on MySQL 5.7 and below..

Comment: hmm no way to search nested array easily???

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) ... As i might have misread that JSON structure and what you are trying to get..  Pretty you need to deal with (dynamic) numeric items here which involves writting tricky SQL..